# git config name via shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have the sh script like

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > logfile.txt 2>&1
date
echo "****** Getting latest pull ******"
cd "/home"
sudo git config --system http.sslVerify false
sudo git config --system user.email "email@email.com"
sudo git config --global user.name username
git reset --hard
git pull  --no-edit origin dev
```

The script running via  `shell_exec('sh pull_and_build.sh');` in php file

The log file seems like :

```
Wed Oct 25 20:28:32 MSK 2023
****** Getting latest pull ******
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
HEAD is now at 272df2968 Merge branch 'dev' of origin into dev
From origin
 * branch                dev        -> FETCH_HEAD

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <host>) not allowed
******************************************
```

1)Seems like script cant run sudo
2)i must to set account's default identity. But when i run it into ssh that doesnot helps
3)i cant set in the git config in sh without sudo